# Filling in a new array in java based off of the old one

Tags: java, arrays, methods, int

I have this problem.  I need to take array x and convert it to array y without using certain methods.

Example time:

```
int[] newArr = new int[5];
newArr[0] = -2;
newArr[1] = 4;
newArr[2] = 2;
newArr[3] = 2;
newArr[4] = 5;
```

which gives

```
arr = {-2, 4, 2, 2, 5};
```

and I need to turn it in to

```
newArr = {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

I am not allowed to use Array, ArrayList, and Vector.  What I have so far is:

```
public static void fillArray(int[] numbers){
    int length = numbers.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++){
        if(numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1]){
            length += numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] - 1;
        }else if(numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]){
            length += numbers[i] - numbers[i + 1] - 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(length);
    int[] newArr = new int[length];
```

Which gives me the length of the new array I need to make.

My question is how would I go about filling in the new array, or with what concepts could I use?

Now yes, this is part of a project for my 00 Design class I am taking.  No I'm not looking for the answer.  I'm looking for ideas (if-statements, for-loops, etc...) that I can maybe implement into my code and what I would use them for.  Unlike a lot of you (I'm generalizing here) I'm not a programmer or skilled in the programming arts.  I'm taking this class because it's required for my major of Chemical Engineering, a profession that doesn't do much in the way of programming with Java.  Because of this, I know what I have to do, I just don't know the syntax well enough to do it myself which is why I'm coming to you all for ideas (NOT ANSWERS) that could maybe work for me and why (i.e. to fill in the array) I would use them.  I asked a similar question earlier and people got mad at me saying I'm just looking for answers and I'm a leecher, I'm not a leecher which is why I'm not looking for answers and having to re-ask this but I am a novice in programming.  Help a novice out will you?  The floor is yours...

**Edit:** Also I forgot to mention I don't know the array being passed in, I just gave an example so putting those numbers in my new array right away is not practical.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but the array doesn't sort the numbers.  It simply fills in the numbers that are in between the elements that are being evaluated.  So I'm creating a new array where numbers[0] = newArr[0] but after that you (or I rather) have to insert the additional numbers into the new array.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would go about it like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<newArr.length;i++){
if(element !in oldArr){
   newArr[i] = i
}else{
 newArr[i] = oldArr[element]
}
 }
```

Comment: And here I am thinking I'm going to need a temp length starting at newArr[i+1] equalling the difference between the numbers - 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to make a new array that fills in the gaps starting with the lowest number of the old array and ending with the highest number of the new array.

Therefore, first you need to find the lowest element in that array.

Second, find the highest number.

Third find the length. The length will be the difference between the highest and the lowest and then add 1 to it. abs(highest - lowest) - 1   abs being absolute value and highest and lowest being integers of course

Lastly use a for loop (or whatever you prefer) to fill the array. There should be two numbers incrementing. for the index of the array and another for the values of the elements that go in the array; it should start at the lowest and increment by one. That should fill the array.

I hope this is clear.Since you stated you don't want the answer but rather ideas, I only explained it to you and left it to you to figure out the code.

Comment: I don't need to start with the lowest and end with the highest.  I start with the first element and end with the last element of the old array.  The array can do anything in between as far as numbers go (i.e. it can go up and it can go down). I have the length of the new array which I cleverly calculated with my for-loop. I guess my biggest problem is how to make it so the program knows with which numbers it needs to fill in the gaps being that the array can have something crazy like {1, 6, 7, 3, -4, 2}

Comment: So if th old array is {-2, 3, -4, 5, 6,-10, 10, 15, -5} what would the new one be?

Comment: If that was the old array, the new one would be {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5}.  Long story short it doesn't sort them it just fills in the numbers in between elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you now.

Since you said you already figured out the code for the length,the next step would be filling in the array:

you are going to have a a nested loop. The outer loop will have the condition on i < newArray.length

The inner loop will keep track of the current element (j) and the next element (j+1), so create another variable that does this. You are going to have to calculate if it is less than or equal than (if statements). If it is less than that inner loop will run until it reaches that element. Obviously the opposite if it is greater. The entire loop should run for the entire length of the new array

This should fill in the gaps

Comment: Alright I'll play with that a bit, thanks I really do appreciate the help and I know it's not easy trying to help without posting the code but I like to understand why it's going to work or not instead of just getting fed answers.

Comment: You are welcome. Definitely, it is important to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach and works as you described.

```
int j = 0;
int[] newArr = new int[]{ -2, 4, 2, 2, 5};
int[] values = new int[13]; // length equals the count you calculated
for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length - 1; i++) {
   int currentNumber = newArr[i];
   int nextNumber = newArr[i+1];
   boolean ascending = currentNumber < nextNumber;
   values[j++] = currentNumber;
   if (ascending) {
      for (int k = 1; k < nextNumber - currentNumber; k++)
      {
         values[j++] = currentNumber + k;
      }
   } else {
      for (int k = 1; k < currentNumber - nextNumber; k++)
      {
         values[j++] = currentNumber - k;
      }
   }
}
values[j++] = newArr[newArr.length - 1];
```